# Move shipping options from order review table before payment options on checkout in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I want to move the shipping options from the order review table before the payment options in the checkout.

I saw, that the order review table has its own template file `review-order.php`.
There I found the following code:

```php
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

---

I know that I could reorder the content from `woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping` and `woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping` with an hook.
But the code starts with an if clause.

So I'm not sure if or how I could move that section to another place in the checkout.

Is there a way I don't see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cut the entire code block and then paste it into another template file within the `checkout` folder

So cut from the `checkout/review-order.php`  template file line [L67-L75](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/checkout/review-order.php#L67-L75)

```php
<?php if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

---

To line [51](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.2.0/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php#L51) in the `checkout/form-checkout.php` template file

```php
    ...
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ); ?>

<?php endif; ?>

<!-- PASTE HERE -->

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review_heading' ); ?>

<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php esc_html_e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
...
```

Comment: OK, I guess there is no way to remove it from the `review-order.php` with a function, right? But I could add it with an hook in the `form-checkout.php`. The problem is, that I'm using an plugin (German Market) which brings its own checkout template and I want to touch as few templates as possible.

Comment: With a hook it is indeed not possible to remove/move without modifying the template file

Comment: Do you have an example? I tried to hook it and remove it from the `review-order.php`. But I had no success.

Comment: I would not see the advantage of it, with a hook you will also have to edit the template files so you would have a hook (custom code) + edited templates files, this answer only contains edited template files, so in the end a 'better' and above all the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer from @7uc1f3r

> You can cut the entire code block and then paste it into another template file within the checkout folder

You can add your plugin's templates folder to WooCommerce's templates search filter, that way you can have your WooCommerce templates in your plugin directory, use the following function:

```
/**
 * Add plugin's templates folder to WooCommerce template locations  
 */
 function af_plugin_templates($template, $template_name, $template_path)
{
    global $woocommerce;
    $_template = $template;
    if (!$template_path)
        $template_path = $woocommerce->template_url;

    $plugin_path  = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/woocommerce/';

    // First check if our plugin has the template
    $file = file_exists($plugin_path . $template_name);
    if ($file)
        $template = $plugin_path . $template_name;

    // Look within passed path within the theme
    if (!$template)
        $template = locate_template(
            array(
                $template_path . $template_name,
                $template_name
            )
        );

    if (!$template)
        $template = $_template;

    return $template;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template',af_plugin_templates', 1, 3);
```

Now you can add your templates in 'your_plugin/templates/woocommerce/...' directory and they will be prioritized.